# Having an issue storing data on firebase (web)

Tags: javascript, database, firebase

What am I doing wrong here...?

Here is my code:

```
var Firebase = require("firebase");
var dbRef = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/");
var dataRef = ref.child("compareData");

dataRef.set({pairedResult});
```

I get the error "bundle.js:81 Uncaught ReferenceError: ref is not defined" on line:

```
var dataRef = ref.child("compareData");
```

I'm copying the method exactly from the documentation on Firebase.

EDIT: "pairedResult" is already defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable name for the Firebase instance is dbRef not ref (which they commonly use in the docs).

Try

```
var dataRef = dbRef.child("compareData");
```